# How to create Empty Label without any entries in it using Google Mail API Ver 2?

Tags: c#, api, email, gmail

I want to create an empty label in Google apps using Google Mail API.
Using Below code:

```
MailItemService mailItemService = new MailItemService(domain, "Sample Migration Application");
mailItemService.setUserCredentials(userEmail, password);

MailItemEntry[] entries = new MailItemEntry[1];

entries[0]              = new MailItemEntry();

entries[0].Labels.Add(new LabelElement("Empty Label"));

entries[0].BatchData    = new GDataBatchEntryData();
entries[0].BatchData.Id = "0"; 

MailItemFeed feed = mailItemService.Batch(domain, username, entries);
```

Above code is not giving any error but not creating label also.

**If i assign some more values to entries it work nicely but it result in cretion of mail inside Label (But i want empty label)**

Can anyone help me out here?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Email Settings API to create labels for an user:

http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/email_settings/developers_guide_protocol.html#GA_email_label_main